# How to get AssemblyInformations

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

In my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, I have attributes like:

```
   [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
   [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2015")]
```

Now i want to get this informations in my `OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)` Method in my `App.xaml.cs`.

When I search for this in the internet and on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) I always solutions like:

```
   System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
   string version = fvi.FileVersion;
```

But this doesn´t work for Windows 10. So is there something similar for Windows 10?

**Edit:**
I am developing an Windows 10 UWP application.

Comment: I work on Windows 10 and I have no problems in getting assembly information on desktop applications, can you specify which kind of applications are you developing?

Comment: I am developing an uwp-application

Comment: Pretty important to de-tune the original .NET versioning think.  Assembly versions are totally irrelevant in UWP.  There never is a DLL Hell problem, there can only ever be one version of your assembly and it can never be the wrong one.  Much more important now is the concept of the package, the actual binary that you deliver.  You *really* care about the package version now.

Comment: @HansPassant thx for the comment, do you maybe have a link or sth. where this is described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find attributes using this code:

```
var currentAsembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var customAttributes = currentAssembly.CustomAttributes;
```

CustomAttributes is IEnumerable object of available atttributes among them you can find information abut assembly and file version

**Edit:**

Here is complete code:

```
var currentAssembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly; 
var customAttributes = currentAssembly.CustomAttributes; 
var list = customAttributes.ToList(); 
var res = list[0]; 
var result = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType.Name == "AssemblyFileVersionAttribute"); 
var ver = result.ConstructorArguments[0].Value;
```

Comment: These lines are working, but could you pls show me, how i get the version out of customAttributes? BTW There is a little typo in currentAssembly, you missed an "s"

Comment: Here is complete code: 

            var currentAssembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var customAttributes = currentAssembly.CustomAttributes;
            var list = customAttributes.ToList();
            var res = list[0];
            var result = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType.Name == "AssemblyFileVersionAttribute");
            var ver = result.ConstructorArguments[0].Value;

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get information about app version in general, you can use Package.Current property.

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel;

Package package = Package.Current;
PackageId packageId = package.Id;
PackageVersion version = packageId.Version;

String output = String.Format(
               "Name: \"{0}\"\n" +
               "Version: {1}.{2}.{3}.{4}\n" +
               "Architecture: {5}\n" +
               "ResourceId: \"{6}\"\n" +
               "Publisher: \"{7}\"\n" +
               "PublisherId: \"{8}\"\n" +
               "FullName: \"{9}\"\n" +
               "FamilyName: \"{10}\"\n" +
               "IsFramework: {11}",
               packageId.Name,
               version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision,
               packageId.Architecture,
               packageId.ResourceId,
               packageId.Publisher,
               packageId.PublisherId,
               packageId.FullName,
               packageId.FamilyName,
               package.IsFramework);
```

Comment: This information took from app manifest file, it more preferable way to work with on uwp. Is package Name and Publisher info not fit to you?

Comment: It matches with the Package.appxmanifest so you are right with Version and Package name . But is there an option to get the PublisherDisplayName and the PackageDisplayName?

Comment: I got it by myself. you get it with package.DisplayName and package.PublisherDisplayName. Thank you for your answer, but i will mark the other one, because my original question was to get the info out of assembly. I hope you understand it

Comment: I understand :). Answer really close but not fit to question. Were glad to help